# Universal analytics with custom dimensions for adblock

Tags: javascript, jquery, analytics, adblock

I am trying to figure out how to track people using adblock addons.
Adblock Plus for example sets the div display: none.

I created a custom dimension in Google Analytics.

I get no errors but have the feeling that will no work as I intend to:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx', 'domain.de');
ga('send', 'pageview');


if ($(".werbung").css('display') == 'none')
        {
            ga('set', 'Adblock', 'Ja');

        }    
    else
        {
            ga('set', 'Adblock', 'Nein');

        }   
</script>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: ABP blocks GA altogether. Nothing will ever get sent. http://kennystechtalk.blogspot.com/2016/03/adblockanalytics.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of handling a situation like this. One of them is exactly as you mentioned in the example provided but there are a couple of others that you can check out here: http://technicalmarketing.io/analytics/track-how-many-of-your-visitors-use-ad-block-style-plugins-in-google-analytics/